# What risers do I need for my Profile Stryke Carbon Ironman aero bars?

Tags: bike-fit, adjustment, comfort, aero-bars

I'd like to improve my comfort on the bike a bit by raising my elbows and shoulders when I use my aero bars. I have Profile Stryke Carbon bars presently. The bars themselves are clamped under my current handlebars, and the elbow-pads are above my current handlebars.

I bought these aero bars second-hand, and I am really uncertain which riser kit is compatible with them.

I presume a riser kit will allow the pads to be placed further from my handlebars, and (I hope) will allow the pads to tilt forward to compensate.

Comment: Have you tried [contacting](https://profile-design.com/pages/contact) Profile Design?

Comment: Yes, I filled out the contact-form on their website. Haven't heard from them yet.